# Fix particle system errors in processing

Tags: javascript, java, processing, system, particles

I'm trying to set up a feather-looking particle system in processing. I am trying to base it off of some code I found on OpenProcessing. When I copy and paste the code into processing (using Java) I get an error saying "expecting SEMI, found 'points'.

I figured this was maybe because the code uses var and not int indicating that this would be Javascript code instead. So I switched the processing mode to p5.js, and it runs but the browser that opens is just a blank white screen.

Any help on getting this to run would be appreciated! Thanks!

The code is below:

```
var points = [];
var painting = false;
var strokeNumber = 0;

var scl = 6;
var cols, rows;
var inc = 0.1;
var zOff = 0;
var particles = [];
var flowField = [];
var saturation = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  // createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(0);
  pixelDensity(5);

  cols = floor(width / scl);
  rows = floor(height / scl);

  flowField = Array(cols * rows);
  saturation = Array(width * height).fill(0);
  greateForceField();

}

function mousePressed() {
  painting = true;
  strokeNumber++;
}

function mouseReleased() {
  painting = false;
}

function updateForceField(){
  var v = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  var vPrev = createVector(pmouseX, pmouseY);
  v.sub(vPrev);
  v.setMag(1);
  var i = floor(mouseX / scl);
  var j = floor(mouseY / scl);
  var index =  i * rows + j;
  flowField[index] = v;
}

function showForceField(){
  for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      var index = i * rows + j;
      var v = flowField[index];
      stroke(0,50);
      strokeWeight(1);
      push();      
      translate(i * scl, j * scl);
      rotate(v.heading());
      line(0,0,scl,0);
      pop();
    }    
  }
}

function greateForceField(){
  var xOff = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    var yOff = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      yOff += inc; 
      var angle = noise(xOff, yOff, zOff) * TWO_PI;
      var v = p5.Vector.fromAngle(angle);
      v.setMag(.1);
      var index = i * rows + j;
      flowField[index] = v;
    }
    xOff += inc;
  }
  // zOff += inc * 0.1;
}

function draw() {
  // background(255);
  // showForceField();

  if(painting){
    updateForceField();

    var idx = mouseY * width + mouseX;
    if(saturation[idx] < 10){
      var r = 1+sqrt(sq(mouseX-pmouseX)+sq(mouseY-pmouseY));
      for(var a = 0; a < 100; a++){
        var particle = new Particle(mouseX+random()*r*cos(random(TWO_PI)), mouseY+random()*r*sin(random(TWO_PI)));
        particles.push(particle);
      }
      saturation[idx] ++;
    }
  }

  particles.filter(particle => particle.spread > 0).map(particle => {
    particle.update();
    particle.show();
    // particle.edges();
    particle.follow();
  })

  particles.map((particle, idx) => {
    if(particle.spread <= 0){
      particles.splice(idx,1);
    }
  });

}

function Particle(x,y){  
  this.pos = createVector(x,y);
  // this.color = color(245, 225, 50);
  // this.color = color(145, 225, 192);
  this.color = color(255);
  this.spread = 127;
  this.spreadInc = this.spread/100;

  this.prevPos = this.pos.copy();
  this.vel = p5.Vector.random2D();
  this.acc = createVector(0,0);
  this.maxSpeed = 2;

  this.update = function(){
    this.spread -= this.spreadInc;
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.vel.limit(this.maxSpeed);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.mult(0);
  }

  this.applyForce = function(force){
    this.acc.add(force);
  }

  this.follow = function(){
    var i = floor(this.pos.x / scl);
    var j = floor(this.pos.y / scl);
    var index =  i * rows + j;
    var force = flowField[index];
    this.applyForce(force);    
  }

  this.show = function(){
    stroke(red(this.color),green(this.color),blue(this.color),this.spread);
    strokeWeight(.3*this.spread/127);
    // point(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    line(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.prevPos.x, this.prevPos.y);
    this.updatePrev();
  }

  this.updatePrev = function(){
    this.prevPos = this.pos.copy();
  }

  this.edges = function(){
    if(this.pos.x > width) {
      this.pos.x = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.x < 0){
      this.pos.x = width;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.y > height){
      this.pos.y = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.y < 0) {
      this.pos.y = height;
      this.updatePrev();
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like javascript waaay more than java. I'm not exactly a buff in these matters, but... are you trying to run javascript as java?

If you are using the Processing IDE, look in the upper right corner. Do you see the word "Java" ?

Like this:

[image]

If this is the case, you might want to consider installing p5.js :

Click here and choose "Add mode":

[image]

Now search for p5.js and install it:

[image]

Now your code will compile. I'm not saying it'll work, though, but your current problem will be behind you. Have fun!